# efficient way to store large amount of html content

Tags: android, sqlite, large-data

I have a database, which has a table with fields like "title, album, artist..." and it also has many fields with html content for every record (up to 30).

Problem is, that this database has tens of thousands of records and is hundreds of megabytes large because of the html content. Because of the size of the sqlite file the search is very slow (also inserting new elements in a transaction is very slow ~10-30 second for 200 new rows). The very first LIKE query can take 10-15 seconds, other searches are fast enough (indices are created and work ok). When I removed the html content from the database the search was always instant.

So the question is, what is the best way to store that additional html content? Right now I play with the option to store it in separate files, but it can generate up to 600k files and more in the future, which is quiet slow to create. Storing the files in a zip archive will probably hit its file number limit. Other options are to zip files per table row, store the html in a separate table in the same database, or to create a separate database file for the html content.

What will give me the best performance? Or are there other better options? I need quick insert, update and serach.

Comment: For the slow inserts, are they all wrapped in a single transaction?  If not, this can greatly slow things down.

Comment: yes, the inserts are wrapped in one transaction and they take 6-20 seconds each. i cannot have more than ~250 records in a transaction because i will get out of memory errors. slow inserts are only if i put the html in the db, otherwise they are inserts are fast.

Comment: do you search based to the html field? and does your index cover the html field?

Comment: i do not search based on the html fields, only based on name, which is indexed

Comment: well then, as for speeding up inserts, you may be limited in terms of options.  If there's a lot of common data between the html fields for separate rows, you could consider trying to abstract it out a little more so that you're just providing links off to the common data, instead of copying that data each time.

Comment: unfortunatelly, the html data is unique for all records

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some days of experimenting I came to this conclusion:

- one database file with one table was the slowest (up to 10 seconds)
- one database with two tables was twice as fast in the worst case scenario as one table
- fastest was to have two separate database files. one with data needed for search and the other for the huge html data. this is almost instant in the worst case ~300ms and in normal usage it is instant

So I reccommend to use two separate database files in this scenario. If someone does not come with a faster/better solution I will accept this as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple different things you could consider doing:

- Split the data into separate tables.  You could then have 1:1 mappings between the tables, and only join them in if necessary, speeding up queries without them.
- Check your indexes.  Just because you have them and you *think* they're working, doesn't mean they are.  If I recall correctly, sqlite will use at most one index per query, so you need to make sure you have the best index possible available for the queries you're using.  The ANALYZE command can help with that.

Comment: (1) i am thinking about spliting it in two tables, but the can the speed of search be improved by this? isn't the slow speed because of the huge file size? (2) indices work, the query compares only one column and there is speed difference if i use '%search%' instead of 'search%', where the first cannot use index according to documentation

Comment: (1) The speed of the search would likely be improved when you aren't returning the html data for sure.  If you always need to return the html data for when you search, this wouldn't give you much  (2) 'search%' would _always_ be faster than '%search%', since it can throw out bad matches after checking the first few characters (or at worst, the first _n_ characters for an _n_ character search term) instead of having to scan the entire field.

Comment: i do not return the html content on search. i use it only when i display a particular record. i think that the slowness is because of the file's size, that the search must jump all over the file. when i do not put the html there, the speed in instant. the '%search' does not use index according to the docs.

Comment: I understand that '%search' does not use the index as per documentation, I was just pointing out that using that as your test for whether or not the search was faster was flawed, since it would be slower even if there was no index.  As for putting the data in a different table, the records for the parent table would be closer together (physically on disk), so the seek time of the harddrive would be reduced.